# Android - detecting beacon disables wifi

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I'm building an app with Alt beacon. This App is detecting beacon properly , but during this time wifi becomes disabled in my **Moto G device - 4.4.2**.

- How can I work with both bluetooth and wifi ?

Comment: which way to check net connetion

Comment: as beacon detected , i am requesting data from server.

Answer (score 0):

Google privides sufficient information on that. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) for Bluetooth and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) for WiFi.